# Windows scheduler with Python script that saves a file

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks

I currently have a Python script that scrapes some data from the internet, then saves it as a `pickle` file. When running this from a terminal with `python filename.py` it saves correctly, since the `Date Modified` field of the `pickle` file changes. However, when running with the built-in scheduler it doesn't actually save the `pickle` file, since the `Date Modified` isn't changed, despite seeing the Python script being executed (terminal opens up and I see the script running).

I ticked the `Run with highest privileges` box in the scheduler, and despite that it doesn't save the `pickle` file. I thought it had to do with it not having write permission, but if it has the highest priviliges, surely it can save a file?

At the scheduled time a terminal opens, so I know it is actually being executed (print a message to make sure), but it doesn't show an error about the fact that it couldn't save the file or anything like that. The only reason I know it's not working is the `Date Modified` field not changing. How can I fix this?

Comment: What happens if you do a search for that file? It looks like Task Scheduler sets the working directory to `C:\Windows\System32` so perhaps the file is being written in there?

Comment: @roganjosh 1 file found (the one that I get by running it manually).

Comment: The other thing to try is to set the absolute file path to the file you expect to be written to. Are you currently using a relative path?

Comment: Also, I just did a search for a random file in `C:\Windows\System32` and it was not returned as a result, so I don't think a general search looks in that directory. You may have to go into the directory yourself and look to see if the pickle file exists.

Comment: Alright, I set it to an absolute path instead and it's actually working now, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Task Scheduler has a default working directory of `C:\Windows\System32`. If you set a relative path to the file you are trying to write, it will likely be written into that directory. If you open a Command Prompt in the directory of your script and run it, the relative path will be that directory. So, you actually have two copies of the pickle file.

If you set an absolute path in your script to the file you want to write to, both methods of running your script will write to the same file.